# how to dynamically set visible fields of a django modelform?

Tags: django, field, modelform

I would like the visible fields of a ModelForm to be determined by the instance of the model class it is built upon.
The ModelForm is built upon the model `protocol` which has a method (`protocol.visiblefields()`)which returns an array of strings corresponding to the fields to be made visible.

forms.py

```
class ListForm(ModelForm):   

    class Meta():
        model = protocol

        fields = []
```

views.py

```
newProtocol = protocol()
form = ListForm(instance=newProtocol)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of options to do this, one is mostly in the view and the other is in the form `__init__`.

**Option 1:** Pop the fields after initializing the form. Although you would need to specify all fields in the form Meta and remove the ones you don't want in the view.

```py
newProtocol = protocol()
form = ListForm(instance=newProtocol)
visible_fields = newProtocol.visiblefields()
for field in form.fields:
    if field not in visible_fields:
        form.fields.pop(field)
```

**Option 2:** Overwrite the `__init__` method and pass the fields in. We include all fields and remove the ones we don't want.

forms.py

```py
class ListForm(ModelForm):   

    class Meta:
        model = protocol
        fields = '__all__'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        visible_fields = kwargs.pop('visible_fields')
        super(ListForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in self.fields:
            if field not in visible_fields:
                self.fields.pop(field)
```

views.py

```
newProtocol = protocol()
form = ListForm(instance=newProtocol, visible_fields=newProtocol.visiblefields())
```

Comment: brilliant, thank you. Tried option 1 and it works. Only issue is it removes (pops) the fields that are intended to be visible. Creating an array of 'invisible fields' and popping them is workaround...`invisible_fields = []
        for field in form.fields:
            if field not in visible_fields:
                invisible_fields.append(field)
        for field in invisible_fields:
            if field in form.fields:
                form.fields.pop(field)`

Comment: My bad, I had it the right way round for option 2, I'll update the answer!

Comment: @NBrown If this worked for you can you mark the answer as accepted?